# Set integer equal to counter and increase counter

Tags: julia

I have a set of integers that act as ids for other variables in my code. I wish to create a list of them, numbered from 1 to N:

```
i_counter = 0

i_counter = i_counter + 1
i_A = i_counter
i_counter = i_counter + 1
i_B = i_counter
```

...

Is there a way to write these in one line? I'd like to be able to rearrange the code line-by-line to change the order of the counters.

Comment: `i_A, i_B, ... = 1:n`?

Comment: or `i_A = i_counter += 1` if for some reason what is proposed above is not something you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Julia, each statement is also an expression, so you can just chain together statements to get what you want.

```
i_counter = 0
i_A = i_counter = i_counter + 1
i_B = i_counter = i_counter + 1
```

or more elegantly, as in Bogumil's comment

```
i_counter = 0
i_A = i_counter += 1
i_B = i_counter += 1
```

In other words, there is no need for anything analogous to Python's new "walrus" operator `:=` in Julia, because every statement such as `i_counter = i_counter + 1` is *already* an expression that returns a value.